# knockout.js ko.mapping.fromjs include one property in binding

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

this is my code which is not working

```
 var getUpdates = setInterval(function () {  
            $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetLists", "Home")?id=" + self.selectedboard(), function (data) {                           
                        var mapping = {
                            // only include these two properties
                            'include': ["cardlists"]
                        }
                        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self.lists);
                        ko.applyBindings(helloWorldModel);
                    });                  
                }, 3000);
```

data is returning

> [{"boardid":1,"boardname":"asdasd","listid":15,"listname":"asdasd","cardvisiblity":true,"showlist":false,"listremove":false,"showRenderTimes":false,"cardlists":[{"cardid":23,"cardname":"7","listid":15},{"cardid":24,"cardname":"3","listid":15},{"cardid":27,"cardname":"asdasd","listid":15},{"cardid":38,"cardname":"asdasd","listid":15}]},{"boardid":1,"boardname":"asdasd","listid":22,"listname":"asdasd","cardvisiblity":true,"showlist":false,"listremove":false,"showRenderTimes":false,"cardlists":[{"cardid":33,"cardname":"asdasd","listid":22},{"cardid":39,"cardname":"asdasd","listid":22},{"cardid":41,"cardname":"qdasd","listid":22}]},{"boardid":1,"boardname":"asdasd","listid":23,"listname":"asdasd","cardvisiblity":true,"showlist":false,"listremove":false,"showRenderTimes":false,"cardlists":[{"cardid":34,"cardname":"asdasd","listid":23},{"cardid":40,"cardname":"asdasd","listid":23}]},{"boardid":1,"boardname":"asdasd","listid":24,"listname":"asdasd","cardvisiblity":true,"showlist":false,"listremove":false,"showRenderTimes":false,"cardlists":[{"cardid":35,"cardname":"qweqwe","listid":24},{"cardid":36,"cardname":"asdasd","listid":24},{"cardid":37,"cardname":"asdasd","listid":24},{"cardid":42,"cardname":"sdfsdf","listid":24},{"cardid":43,"cardname":"asdasd","listid":24}]}]

How can include only cardlists in the binding?

how can i exclude showRenderTimes in the binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `include` keyword you can only add any properties that **is** **not** **already** part of your original object.

By using `ignore` keyword you can specify those properties of your object that you don't want to map.

So in your case you can specify all properties that you don't want to be part of mapping and only have `cardlists` left there.

**'ignore'**

```
var mapping = {
    'ignore': ["boardid", "boardname","listid","cardvisiblity","showlist","listremove","showRenderTimes"]
}
 ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, self.lists);
```

Comment: ignore means for example if cardvisiblity is false it will remain false? if it is coming true from it will not be affected

Comment: No, it means if `cardvisiblity` is part of your object you tell mapping plugin to ignore this property from mapping. It won't be part of binding model.

Comment: cardvisiblity will not be part of self.lists?

Comment: True. If you add it to the array of property name to ignore it wont be there . It's good to take a look at this http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html